# How to modify what IQueryable returns at run-time?

Tags: c#

I am failing to see how, if possible, to set values in an entity returned by an `IQueryable`.

So take the following code as an example:

```
public IQueryable<CustomerInfo> CustomerInfoAsQueryable()
{
    IQueryable<CustomerInfo> customerInfo = _dbCustomerService.Info("CustomerID123");

    // Note: customerInfo.Logbook has value "~/dir/logbook.txt"

    // How to set customerInfo.LogbookContent to the contents of "~/dir/logbook.txt"

    return customerInfoAsQueryable;
}
```

Now I have to pass `CustomerInfoAsQueryable` to a 3rd party control, so that they can do the query. I'd like to be able to read `customerInfo.Logbook` and find the file then read the content of the file finally set `customerInfo.LogbookContent` to this content.

I guess this is kind of lazy loading.

How can I do this to allow the 3rd party control get the `customerInfo.LogbookContent` when they make a query for different customers?

(Note: how to read the file is not the subject of question)

Comment: CustomerInfo sould implement an interface that provides an access to LogbookContent.

Comment: @PepitoSh thank you for the reply. That would have worked, except that the CustomerInfo is in the DB layer as it needs to be lazy loaded(for performance). I can't perform this operation there. Is there any trick to do it in the above function?

Comment: An extension method to CustomerInfo?

Comment: @PepitoSh thanks again for your reply. Unfortunately I don't think that will help. The LogbookContent is a property. I also can't use static classes as I am using Autofac and it will get dirty if I venture into static classes.

Comment: Why are you storing the value of `LogbookContent` in a file rather than in your database ?

Comment: I have simplified the example above to explain the problem. In reality, I have a scenario where a customer has many documents associated with them which could be large. So to avoid SQL costs (cloud based) I will be keeping this data on a different storage such as AWS S3 or Azure Storage.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to read the specified file only when `customerInfo.LogbookContent` is called ? (a kind of lazy file loading)

Comment: @Spotted, yes exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer your question I would warn you about the practise of returning an `IQueryable` from a repository which is [considered a bad practice](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/02/08/specification-pattern-c-implementation/) because it encourages business logics spreading across application layers.
It would be better to take the filters and return a read-only filtered result.

Then something is bothering me about `CustomerInfo.LogbookContent`. The class `CustomerInfo` is supposed to reflect a table structure in some database. Thus, having this field is misleading: one think this information is stored inside the database although it is absolutely not the case. Plus, there is some redundancy with `CustomerInfo.Logbook` which specifies a path. How to know where the information is ? That's the reason I believe that it would be better to remove `CustomerInfo.LogbookContent`.

There is one other thing that bothers me: the fact that some filepaths are leaking out of your persistence layer (in `CustomerInfo.Logbook`) and I would do all my possible to avoid that. You can see [this video](https://vimeo.com/162209391) to understand why it is a good idea to restrict your API as much as possible (in short it lead to both better design and security).

Based on these remarks, I came to the conclusion that you need a new level of abstraction based on top of `CustomerInfo` to better serve your users.

I would come up this a design like this:

```
public IReadOnlyList<Customer> GetCustomers(/*some filters (id = ..., name like ..., etc.)*/)
{
    return _dbCustomerService.Info("CustomerID123")
                             .Where(/*some filters (id = ..., name like ..., etc.)*/)
                             .Select(ci => new Customer(ci.Name, GetLogbookContent(ci.Logbook))
                             .ToList();
}

private string GetLogbookContent(string localFilePath)
{
    //Connect to AWS/Azure
    //Return file's content
}

public sealed class Customer
{
    public Customer(string name, string logbook)
    {
        Name = name;
        Logbook = logbook;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Logbook { get; }
}
```

A few notes about this code:

- The logbook's content is **not** lazy-loaded. On the other hand, it is only loaded for relevant `Customer`. I believe this is a proper way to do because if your user want these customers it makes sense to follow the least astonishment principle and fetch the data to avoid a long call later when it could be problematic because it is not expected (UI freezing, etc.).
- I added a `Customer` class which contains only relevant information for your user and completely abstracts the fact that the data comes from both a database and a file stored on some cloud storage
- I explicitely return an `IReadOnlyList` to clearly specify that we are done with any persistence and the result is now in memory (otherwise the persistance layer can be closed before the `IQueryable` is really executed => hello nightmare debugging).

Now if **and only if** calling `GetCustomers` takes really too long because of the file loading it is still possible to make the following refactor to enable logbook's lazy-loading:

```
public IReadOnlyList<Customer> Get(/*some filters (id = ..., name like ..., etc.)*/)
{
    return _dbCustomerService.Info("CustomerID123")
                             .Where(/*some filters (id = ..., name like ..., etc.)*/)
                             .Select(ci => new Customer(ci.Name, () => GetLogbookContent(ci.Logbook))
                             .ToList();
}

public sealed class Customer
{
    private string _logbook;
    private readonly Func<string> _loadLogbook;
    public Customer(string name, Func<string> logbook)
    {
        Name = name;
        _loadLogbook = logbook;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Logbook
    {
        get
        {
            if (_logbook == null)
            {
                _logbook = _loadLogbook();
            }
            return _logbook;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this allows to load the logbook from the cloud storage only once (the first time). However if the content of this file is constantly changing and you need to know that (=load the file content on each call of `Customer.Logbook`) you could refactor `Customer` like this:

```
public sealed class Customer
{
    private readonly Func<string> _loadLogbook;
    public Customer(string name, Func<string> logbook)
    {
        Name = name;
        _loadLogbook = logbook;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Logbook => _loadLogbook();
}
```

## Update

According to your comments you can't bypass the two assumptions I initially made:

- You have to return an `IQueryable`
- You cannot return something else than `CustomerInfo`

Based on that here's how I would implement the lazy file loading (I assumed that `CustomerInfo` looks like a POCO class, which is often the case for a class used by some ORM):

```
public class CustomerInfo
{
    private Func<string, string> _loadLogbook;
    private string _logbookContent;
    ...
    public void SetLoadLogbook(Func<string, string> loadLogbook) => _loadLogbook = loadLogbook;
    ...
    public string Logbook { get; set; }
    public string LogbookContent
    {
        get
        {
            if(_logbookContent == null)
            {
                _logbookContent = _loadLogbook?.Invoke(Logbook);
            }
            return _logbookContent;
        }
        set => _logbookContent = value;
    }
    ...
}
```

And `CustomerInfoAsQueryable` becoming:

```
public IQueryable<CustomerInfo> CustomerInfoAsQueryable()
{
    return _dbCustomerService.Info("CustomerID123")
                             .Select(ci =>
                             {
                                 ci.SetLoadLogbook(path => GetLogbookContent(path));
                                 return ci;
                             });
}
```

Notes:

- The lazy-loading behavior is not injected via a setter, which is something I would call "last resort injection". Indeed a setter injection is more dangerous than a constructor injection (reliable), hence the `_loadLogbook?` which protect your code from a `NullReferenceException` in case `SetLoadLogbook` is not called.
- I was forced to slightly abuse LINQ Select statement by introducing a block expression with a side-effect (which allows me to inject the behavior).

This solution is as you know suboptimal but (should) work with your constraints.

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer. I learned a lot from it. One of the reasons that I have to return an IQueryable is that I need to pass it to a 3rd party component. I can't even seem to slightly manipulate it by say using a `Select` to project the properties and as soon as I do that it won't present the values in the UI. So the component uses IQueryable to do paging. If I use the .ToList(), as you have rightly mentioned in the above case, it won't be lazy loaded. This results in much slower performance if I load the db with 200K records.

Comment: For now I have worked around the issue by using the above two variables in the View. I use Html.Action to read the content for the current user. I also have to set `customerInfo.LogbookContent` to the value of `customerInfo.Logbook` when doing CRUD. But when presenting on the UI, `customerInfo.LogbookContent` will have the content. I know...terrible. But it works. From security perspective, each user will have their own container(Some GUID). The action method(GET) only accepts the path to the blob(GUID), but not the container name and the user has to be authenticated for using that action.

Comment: @b3hdad I understand. I provided an update to your problem which takes your constraints into account

Comment: @b3hdad Regarding the security perspective (GUID), I'm not sure I understand your point. However I'm also not sure it is relevant to your original problem.

Comment: thank you so much again for the solution. Yes, I have managed to conceptually implement what you suggested. I had a few heck ups with the linq but got it to work. Will impelment it soon replacing my old method. About the security and the Guid please ignore as i was typing out loud. Thanks again for your help.